# Cakephp-3.0 How to create custom rule in plugin behavior

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Please how can i create custom rule function in cakephp 3.0 plugin behavior, like we can do in 2.x version :

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

thanks in advance !

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: yeah but isn't worked !

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#adding-validation-providers**